# JList search with setSelectedIndices always selects first item

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlist

I've just started learning about GUIs, so I'll apologize prematurely for any amateur mistakes in my code.

I've been trying to implement a simple search option for a Jlist/JScrollPane window, which highlights all Jlist items that contain the search keyword. The search works almost as I want it to, save for the fact that the first item in the list is always selected in each new search, even if it doesn't fit the search criteria.

Here's the code snippet of the search function itself (I tried using an ArrayList instead of just an Array, hoping that would fix it, but it hasn't):

```
    // Setup Search button/Assign Listener
    JButton btSearch = new JButton("Search");
    btSearch.addActionListener( (e) -> {
        String input = tfSearch.getText();
        int[] searchArray = new int[database.length];
        ArrayList<Integer> searchList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i<database.length; i++) //Search for entries that contain user input
            {
                if (database[i].contains(input))
                {
                    searchList.add(i);
                }
            }

        for (int i=0; i<searchList.size(); i++) //Convert ArrayList to Array
        {
            searchArray[i] = searchList.get(i);
        }

        lister.setSelectedIndices(searchArray);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an array that has the size of the JList. So it's filled with zeroes nitially. Then you overwrite the first elements of the array with actual selected indices. But there are still zeroes at the end of the array.

You need to create an array containing only the selected indices:

```
int[] searchArray = searchList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Or, if you prefer while loops:

```
int[] searchArray = new int[searchList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < searchList.size(); i++) {
    searchArray[i] = searchList.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Oooooh, shit. I totally missed that; I thought I changed it to the ArrayList, but alas...

Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @JoshMac, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark, so people know the problem has been solved.